# Get last row from group, limit number of results in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table with records representing a log, I omit rest of the columns in this example.

The `id`-column is autoincrement, `item_id` represents an item in app.

I need to get the latest `item_id`, for example two or three

```
CREATE TABLE "log" (
    "id" INT,
    "item_id" INT
);

-- TRUNCATE TABLE "log";
INSERT INTO "log" ("id", "item_id") VALUES
    (1, 1),
    (2, 2),
    (3, 1),
    (4, 1),
    (5, 3),
    (6, 3);
```

Basic query will list all results, latest at the top:

```
SELECT *
FROM "log"
ORDER BY "id" DESC
```

```
id  item_id
6   3
5   3
4   1
3   1
2   2
1   1
```

I would like to have just two (LIMIT 2) last item_ids with their id. Last means - inserted last (ORDER BY id).

```
id  item_id
6   3
4   1
```

Last three would be

```
id  item_id
6   3
4   1
2   2
```

Once an `item_id` is returned, it is not returned again. So `LIMIT 4` would return only three rows because there are only three unique `item_id`.

I am probably missing something. I already tried various combinations of `DISTINCT OF`, `GROUP BY`, `LIMIT` etc.

---

**UPDATE #1:**
After I tested query by S-man (below), I found out that it works for the data I provided howerer it does not work in general, for another set of data (sequence of `item_id` A, B and A again.). Here is another data set:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE "log";
INSERT INTO "log" ("id", "item_id") VALUES
    (1, 1),
    (2, 2),
    (3, 3),
    (4, 3),
    (5, 1),
    (6, 3);
```

Data in DB, ordered by `id` desc:

```
id  item_id
6   3
5   1
4   3
3   3
2   2
1   1
```

Expected result for last three `item_id`

```
6   3
5   1
2   2
```

Comment: Could you please show the expected result of your first example with LIMIT 4? As I understand now: When a value for a specific item_id was recognized once, it should never be returned again. Right?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I updated the question. If item_id is returned, it should not be returned (repeated) again. If there are just three unique item_ids, LIMIT 4 (or query without LIMIT) would return three rows only.

Comment: Why do you keep changing your question?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after three changes, now we come back to the very first idea:

Just take `DISTINCT ON`:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=08712f654f78cb12fdee50e86d22ff86)

```
SELECT
    *
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (item_id)   -- 1
        *
    FROM log
    ORDER BY item_id, id DESC
) s
ORDER BY id DESC                   -- 2
LIMIT 2
```

1. Returns exact one record of an ordered group. You group is the `item_id`, the order is id `DESC`, so you get the highest id for each item_id
2. Reorder by id `DESC` (instead of the previously ordered `item_id`) and limit your query output.

Comment: Changed answer, added explanation

Comment: I tried your query on a larger dataset and found out that it works on a simple example I provided however on larger dataset it returned unwanted result. I think the reason was if there was a sequence of item_id A, B, and A again, the query returned A again. I updated the question.

Comment: Hold on, after going too much ways, it came to my mind, after you clarifying, that the very first approach is now the very best, at all. :D :D Changed the answer, hopefully the last time